# How to show a widget for 4 seconds Using Timer in Flutter

Tags: user-interface, flutter

I created the UI for a splash screen in the BuildWaitingScreen widget.I want to display the Splash screen    in the widget called buildWaitingScreen for 4 seconds. I want to know how to give a waiting time for this widget? It Is possible to use Timer for this or Future Delay to get a 4 seconds delay ?

code:`

```
Widget buildWaitingScreen() {
      return Scaffold(
          body: Stack(
            fit: StackFit.expand,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blueAccent),
              ),
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: Container(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                            radius: 50.0,
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.directions_car,
                              color: Colors.blue,
                              size: 50.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "CarWash Locator v.1",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 24.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "one click! locate car wash!!",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 18.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              )
            ],
          )
      );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    switch (authStatus) {
      case AuthStatus.NOT_DETERMINED:
        return buildWaitingScreen();
        break;
      case AuthStatus.NOT_LOGGED_IN:
        return new LandingPage(auth: widget.auth,);
        break;
      case AuthStatus.LOGGED_IN:
        if (_userId.length > 0 && _userId != null) {
          return new HomePage(auth: widget.auth,);
        } else
          return  buildWaitingScreen();
        break;
      default:
        return buildWaitingScreen();
    }
  }
}
```

`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe its too late, but if someone still need the answer, here we are.

So i tried [@Santosh Anad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61412368/15610859) answer and it works.
I will try to make it clear.

First you need to initiate a bool type variable in your class to control your (show/hide) widget.

```
bool _showWidget = true // When the val true, it will show the widget
```

then in your initState() add this Future code:

```
Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3)).then((value) {
  setState(() {
    _showWidget = false;
  });
});
```

then in your widget add condition to know when to hide/show:

```
SizedBox(
  child: _showWidget
    // If _showWidget true, return this widget
    ? Text('This widget will show!')
    
    // If _showWidget false, return null
    : null
),
```

Any question or improvement are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Use this.

```
Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 4)).then((value) => {
    // hide your widget
  });
```

Comment: I put this in the Init state and place my widget inside it but not works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try this to solve the problem, works well for me..

```
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {


  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {

void route(){
  Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Route to your widgets));
}

initiateRoute(){
  var duration = Duration(seconds: 3);
  return Timer(duration, route);
}

  @override
  void initState() {
    initiateRoute();
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```